# Applying styling to html email in SendGrid Web API

Tags: css, html-email, styling, sendgrid

I am sending email from using SendGrid's Web API using POST. The HTML email body has styling associated with it.

[image: Screenshot of the email body]

```
String body = 'api_user=username&api_key=pwd&to[]=user@email.com&subject=Message from SendGrid&html={text}&from=user2@email.com';

    body = body.replace('{text}', emailBody);
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setbody(body);
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse response = http.send(req);
```

However when the email is received, it has no body, none at all. If I remove the inline CSS from the p and div the body is rendered. How do I keep the styling intact in the HTML body? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hunch is that this is related to the '=' in 'style="'

Try URL encoding emailBody:

```
body = body.replace('{text}', encodeURIComponent(emailBody));
```

Comment: Your hunch was right. Had to do EncodingUtil.urlEncode(emailBody, 'UTF-8'); to get the email in the desired format.